# Difference in SQL queries with or without parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me what the difference (besides the obvious) is between these two queries: 
1)

```
declare @coy_oid varchar
declare @field_name varchar

set @coy_oid = '10'
set @field_name = 'ResultReason'

SELECT OID, POSITION, DESCRIPTION, FIELD_NAME 
FROM T_FIELD_TEXT_CHOICES 
WHERE COY_OID = @coy_oid AND FIELD_NAME = @field_name
```

2)

```
declare @coy_oid varchar
declare @field_name varchar

set @coy_oid = '10'
set @field_name = 'ResultReason'

SELECT OID, POSITION, DESCRIPTION, FIELD_NAME 
FROM T_FIELD_TEXT_CHOICES
WHERE COY_OID = @coy_oid AND FIELD_NAME = 'ResultReason'
```

The first one returns nothing and the second returns the expected results. I am sure it has to do with the FIELD_NAME being a variable, but I don't know why.

Guess I should add this is SQL Server 2008 R2, but maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: you need to define a size while defining the type as char/varchar/nvarchar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're variables are declared as `varchar`. That's a single character, so in the first query you're comparing with 'R'. You probably meant to use something like `varchar(100)`...

Comment: That makes perfect sense now.

Comment: hahaha, so varchar means varchar(1) ??? what a stupid default, not to mention the lack of warning for truncation......

Answer (score 3):

`varchar` is the equivalent of `varchar(1)`

To see this consider

```
DECLARE @v1 VARCHAR
SET @v1 = '12345'

DECLARE @v2 VARCHAR (5)
SET @v2 = '12345'

SELECT @v1 AS v1, @v2 AS v2
```

which returns

```
'1' for v1 
'12345' for v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
 declare @coy_oid varchar(100)
 declare @field_name varchar(100)
```